# C# Memory keeps increasing when firing MIDI-events processed by DryWetMidi

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-leaks, midi

I am currently working with the `DryWetMidi` package to control the KORG nanoKONTROL2 MIDI board with `C#`/`.Net` and I noticed that the memory of my application will increase when I fire a lot of MIDI messages (in other words: when I move the faders a lot).

For inspection purposes, I wrote this simple code, which basically does nothing but initializing the `DryWetMidi` package to start listening to MIDI messages send by my device. Then I have 100 seconds to try out various faders/buttons/knobs (and send a lot of MIDI messages)

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    InputDevice nano = InputDevice.GetByName("nanoKONTROL2");
    nano.StartEventsListening();

    Console.WriteLine("start");
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(i + " seconds passed");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("end");

    nano.StopEventsListening();
    nano.Dispose();

}
```

The memory starts increasing by approx. 15MB when I move the faders a lot. The memory only increases when I move anything (when the board sends MIDI messages)! Since the memory does not increase further after these 15MB, I assume that there are some logging processes going on in the background? Or is it some kind of memory leak?

Now my question:

Is there any way to prevent this memory increase?

Comment: Hmm... I've been using this package for a while with no problem. Will test with my X-Touch Mini...

Comment: (Ah - I don't use StartEventsListening, which may explain the difference. Will test with that.)

Comment: I'm the author of DryWetMIDI. Memory increased due to a lot of instances of `MidiEvent` created during moving device controls. Looks reasonable. There are no any logging within the library. Is the problem with 15 MB only? Do you see memory releasing then?

Comment: @Maxim Yes the 15MB are the only problem. Although 15MB is not a big deal for my code itself, it just seems like "unneccessary used memory"  if it stays occupied when I don't send midi messages anymore. And at least in the tests I did (only a few minutes long) there was always the same behavior: Once the memory usage increased, it never decreased. I can make another (longer running) test to check whether the memory stays occupied or whether it is released, but at a slow rate.

Comment: Well, I'll look into memory profiler tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the DryWetMIDI library. I've passed MIDI events receiving through .NET memory profiler and here my conclusions:

1. Yes, memory increased due to new instances of `MidiEvent` class created by DryWetMIDI when new data arrived from a device.
2. GC works as expected. If memory not released, then GC thinks it's not needed right now. In my tests I sent a lot of note events, memory grows and then released.

I don't see any problems. There are no memory leaks and of course there is no any logging within the library. What you see is how .NET memory management works.

Comment: thanks! I now checked it again, but this time using `GC.Collect()` . Now the memory gets released. It really seems like a .NET behavior and not a behavior of your library.